# Arithmetic mean of 4 numbers word problem

Tags: arithmetic, average

Encountered this in a timed online test, only allowing 20 seconds per question:

> The average (arithmetic mean) of 4 numbers is greater than 8 but less
> than 14. Which of the following could not be the sum of these four
> numbers?
>
> Answer choices: 44, 53, 38, 31, 48

8 x 4 is 32 and 14 x 4 is 56, so the sum should be somewhere between 32 and 56, NOT inclusive, is that correct (thus the answer being 31)

I've seen a variation of this question where one of the answers was 32 itself. If the average is greater than 8, wouldn't that mean it's >32 - not inclusive?

What is this question looking for?

Comment: Your answer is correct, and yes, if the average is greater than $8$, the sum must be strictly greater than $32$. The point is apparently to see whether you understand the relationship between the mean and the sum, and whether you can do some very elementary arithmetic quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct. Since the average must be *greater* than $8$, it cannot include $8$. And since $8\cdot 4 = 32$, when adding all the terms, you can't have $32$. This also means you cannot have $56$; all numbers must be between $32$ and $56$ non-inclusive, so $$33, 34, \dots, 54, 55.$$